# Material-UI and Typescript

Tags: material-ui

I am new to TypeScript and trying to follow the example provided in material-ui repository. The example code provided is passing `root` CSS class. I want to pass few more CSS classes along with `root'.

```
const styles: StyleRulesCallback<'root'> = theme => ({
  root: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 20,
  }
});
```

Here is the link for full example code provided by material-ui.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/examples/create-react-app-with-typescript/src/pages/index.tsx

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it like this way:

```
const styles: StyleRulesCallback = theme => ({
    paper: {
        maxWidth: 1000,
        minWidth: 1000,
        display: 'inline-block'
    },
    table: {
        maxWidth: 1000,
    },
});
```

And use the class in your component like this:

```
 <Paper className={classes.paper}>
```

Look at this boilderplate as reference:
https://github.com/innFactory/create-react-app-material-typescript-redux

Answer (score 1):

What Toni gives does not appear to work anymore in `4.1.1` (the one I am using). Instead, you need something like the following

```
import { StyleRulesCallback, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

interface IComponentProps {
  // props
}

const styles: StyleRulesCallback<Theme, IComponentProps> = theme = ({
  someClass: {}
  someClassWithProps: (props) => ({})
})
```

Or, if you prefer to use `createStyles`

```
import { createStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

interface IComponentProps {
  // props
}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  someClass: {}
  someClassWithProps: (props: IComponentProps) => ({})
});
```